# Symfony Routing: Options in Annotations

Tags: symfony

In symfony2, in the routing YAML configurations, you can have an array of options. It looks like this:

```
example_route:
    pattern: /test/route
    options:
        option1: value1
        option2: value2
```

Some of the routes however, are defined within Annotations instead for pretty specific reasons, but I need to add some "options" to those.

I only see a few fields for Annotations, like:

```
@Route and @Method
@ParamConverter
@Template
@Cache
@Security
```

and none of those appear to allow injection into the Route objects Options array.

Is there a solution to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's not documented, the @Route annotation sets other route properties the using the same syntax as requirements and defaults:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello_world", requirements={"name" = "\w+"}, defaults={"name" = "World"}, options={"option" = "value"})
 */
```

Comment: Very nice! You saved me. <3

Comment: How can I get the value in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean route requirements?  I don't think options: is a valid configuration for a route, but there is of course defaults, requirements, etc.

With annotations, the route requirement is part of the @Route attribute:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="hello_world", requirements={"name" = "\w+"}, defaults={"name" = "World"})
 */
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html